# How can I remove the numbers at the end of the product title?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can't get rid of the ellipsis and the hyphen. Is there anyone who can help?

Using the code below I was finally able to remove the Stock Codes at the end of the Product Title. But I still couldn't get rid of the hyphen and there are three dots at the end of the product titles.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorten_woo_product_title', 10, 2 );
function shorten_woo_product_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) {
        return wp_trim_words( $title, -1 ); // change last number to the number of WORDS you want
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
```

I had this;

T-shirt - 953854864

Now there is this;

T-shirt -...

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `wp_trim_words()` you can give it an optional third parameter to specify what it puts on the end of the string to replace the words it has truncated, which defaults to the ellipsis you are seeing. I'd probably try passing in a space (not a null, as that's the default) to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorten_woo_product_title', 10, 2 );
        function shorten_woo_product_title( $title, $id ) {
        if ( get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) {
        // Removes the specified characters and replaces consecutive spaces with a single space
        $title = preg_replace( "/[\s\-.0-9&#;]+/", ' ', $title );
        // Clears spaces at the beginning and end of the header
        $title = trim( $title );
        }return $title;
        }
```

Thank you very much. For some reason the code you wrote didn't work on my site. This is how I got rid of the characters I don't want; @LoicTheAztec